# Marker and Overlay not displayed at the same place

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I use the branflake2267 google maps API for GWT (https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api).
I would like to display a title below a marker.

My location:

```
    final LatLng latlng = LatLng.newInstance(47.4125, -0.861944);
```

The icon marker (it is the correct location on the map)

```
    MarkerImage icon = MarkerImage.newInstance("/images/maps/pin_workshop.png", Size.newInstance(21, 34), Point.newInstance(0, 0), Point.newInstance(10, 34));
    MarkerImage shadow = MarkerImage.newInstance("/images/maps/shadow.png", Size.newInstance(40, 37), Point.newInstance(0, 0), Point.newInstance(12, 35));

    MarkerOptions options = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
    options.setPosition(latlng);
    options.setMap(map);
    options.setTitle("Factory");
    options.setIcon(icon);
    options.setShadow(shadow);

    Marker marker = Marker.newInstance(options);
```

The overlay with the title (Incorrect position in the map...):

```
    final DivElement div = Document.get().createDivElement();

    OverlayView.newInstance(map, new OverlayViewOnDrawHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(OverlayViewMethods methods) {
            Point position = methods.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latlng);

            div.getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
            div.getStyle().setLeft(position.getX(), Unit.PX);
            div.getStyle().setRight(position.getY(), Unit.PX);

            div.setInnerText("Factory");
        }
    },

    new OverlayViewOnAddHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAdd(OverlayViewMethods methods) {                                
            methods.getPanes().getOverlayLayer().appendChild(div);
        }
    },

    new OverlayViewOnRemoveHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRemove(OverlayViewMethods methods) {
            div.removeFromParent();
        }
    });
```

[image: screenshot]

I try different version of the library (3.09 build 17, 3.10.0-alpha-6), and also different panes (getMapPane(), getFloatPane()) without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just using setLeft and setRight instead of setLeft and **setTop**...